# hr has a black pixel underneath it?

Tags: html, css

We have a hr line and there is a weird black pixel underneath it.

Screenshot: http://i52.tinypic.com/2vwxy78.jpg

Our code:

HTML:

```
<hr />
```

CSS:

```
hr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    margin: 12px 0 18px;
}
```

Browser:
Firefox

Why is this pixel appearing underneath the `<hr />`? How do we fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *reset* all the `border` properties for the `<hr>`. Particularly the left border in your case. So:

```
border: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
....
```

Check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/uwed3/

Comment: No prob. I made my brain hurt a few months back on the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't removed the default style on the `<hr>` element.

Add this to your CSS:

```
border-left: 0;
```

And you should be fixed.